# Running out of memory when trying to perform task with apply rather than for loop in R

Tags: r, memory, apply, transpose

I'm trying to rewrite some old code in order for it to be more efficient. I read in my places that using apply should be faster than using a for loop, so I attempted to do this. First the old working code:

```
dl=data.frame(replicate(16,1:15685849))
#in line below mean was sums, but this gave integer overflows. This is not the case in the real dataset, but for the purpose of this example mean will do.
sums<-mapply(mean, dl[,4:ncol(dl)], USE.NAMES=FALSE)
appel<-dl[,1:3]
for (i in 1:(ncol(dl)-3)){
  appel[,i+3]=dl[,i+3]/sums[i]
}
```

No problems so far. I was trying to rewrite this code as a function so I can maken an R package for private use. This was my attempt

```
dl=data.frame(replicate(16,1:15685849))
depthnormalise=function(tonormtable, skipleftcol=3){
    sums<-mapply(mean, dl[,4:ncol(dl)], USE.NAMES=FALSE)
    dn=function(x){x/sums}
    tonormtable[,(skipleftcol+1):ncol(tonormtable)]=t(apply(tonormtable[,(skipleftcol+1):ncol(tonormtable)], 1, dn))
}
appel=depthnormalise(dl)
```

but this will run me out of memory.

I have very little experience using apply, but I can't seem to get it figured out properly for a table where I want to leave the first 3 columns as is and only change the ones after that. If any more information is required please let me know before downvoting! If you only downvote, I won't get better.

Comment: No, `*apply` loops are not faster than a well-written `for` loop. However, "well-written"  means that you pre-allocate the results object to its final size.

Comment: So if I were to use appel=dl  rather than appel=dl[,1:3] in my first code example, this would suffice as a "well written" for loop, and there would be no point in trying to get an apply loop working?

Comment: Yes, it would suffice.

Comment: Do not expect to gain a lot of speed by using applys. If there is a problem with speed or memory, try the data.table package which can change values in place and without making a lot of copies of the data. As to your code, it is really hard to read.  --could you write the code in for both examples similar, like define `dn` in both variants and use `round`in both variants and use similar variable names in both variants?

Comment: `apply` makes additional copies here, because it coerces your data.frame into a matrix. However, one could argue that a matrix would be the more appropriate data structure for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working `apply` solution:

```
appel1 <- as.matrix(dl)
appel1[, -(1:3)] <- apply(appel1[, -(1:3)], 2, 
                          function(x) round(x / mean(x) * 1e6, digits=2))
all.equal(as.matrix(appel), appel1)
#[1] TRUE
```

However, as said in the comments, it won't be faster than a well-written `for` loop. It's slower on my system.

Comment: Alright, I will stick with the for loop then. Still nice to know a solution, however.